# Can Make be made to understand that a/../z and b/../z are the same location?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a somewhat large and complex Makefile setup that postprocesses some data files.  Overall it work quite well, but I have run into an annoying issue where Make builds the same target many times over under different directory names.

As a simple example, consider the Makefile

```
foo : 1/foo 2/foo
    cat $^ > $@

%/foo : %/../bar
    cat $^ > $@

%/bar : %/baz
    cat $^ > $@
```

Initialized with file `baz` and directories `1` and `2`, make will produce the following series of builds, when done in parallel mode:

```
cat 1/../baz > 1/../bar
cat 2/../baz > 2/../bar
cat 2/../bar > 2/foo
cat 1/../bar > 1/foo
cat 1/foo 2/foo > foo
rm 2/../bar
```

Note how the first two commands do exactly the same thing.

Is there a way of convincing Make that `1/../bar` and `2/../bar` are the same file, so it only should do that recipe once?

Comment: In the case of symlinks, they might *not* be.

Comment: This is true; I suppose there is a plenty good reason for that to not be the default.  Never the less, it would be nice if that the assertion that doing so is safe could be made.

Comment: It might be nice for make to support comparing inodes to figure this out but I'm not sure how useful that would be in general (and/or how cheap or not that would be though I don't imagine it would be too bad). I'm not sure there's anything you can do here to make this work out better other than to not use relative paths like that. If you were to use `%/foo: bar` (assuming the only `foo` is one directory down from the root) then make would know there was only one such file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using relative path, you can use absolute path by using the [realpath or abspath](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions) functions:

> `$(realpath names…)`
>
> For each file name in names return the canonical absolute name. A canonical name does not contain any . or .. components, nor any repeated path separators (/) or symlinks. In case of a failure the empty string is returned. Consult the `realpath(3)` documentation for a list of possible failure causes.
>
> `$(abspath names…)`
>
> For each file name in names return an absolute name that does not contain any . or .. components, nor any repeated path separators (/). Note that, in contrast to realpath function, abspath does not resolve symlinks and does not require the file names to refer to an existing file or directory. Use the wildcard function to test for existence.

```
$(abspath foo): $(abspath 1/foo) $(abspath 2/foo)
        cat $^ > $@

%/foo: $(abspath %/../bar)
        cat $^ > $@

%/bar: %/baz
        cat $^ > $@
```

Or something like that:

```
TOP := $(abspath .)

$(TOP)/foo: $(TOP)/1/foo $(TOP)/2/foo
        cat $^ > $@

%/foo: $(abspath %/../bar)
        cat $^ > $@

%/bar: %/baz
        cat $^ > $@
```

Here is the result

```
jmlemetayer@prometheus:~/foobar$ make -j5
cat /home/jmlemetayer/foobar/baz > /home/jmlemetayer/foobar/bar
cat /home/jmlemetayer/foobar/bar > /home/jmlemetayer/foobar/1/foo
cat /home/jmlemetayer/foobar/bar > /home/jmlemetayer/foobar/2/foo
cat /home/jmlemetayer/foobar/1/foo /home/jmlemetayer/foobar/2/foo > /home/jmlemetayer/foobar/foo
rm /home/jmlemetayer/foobar/bar
```

Comment: There's one catch with this -- the `%` did not expand.  The example works because the parent path is fine, but in a "nested somewhere" example it did not.  The solution to this was to use the `.SECONDEXPANSION` feature so that `$$(abspath %/../foo)` runs the abspath function on the expanded directory.